# How to implement the SelectedDate.Value.AddDay() methode in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a textBlock that shows the next day of a selected date from a datePicker, so basically the day after.

I use the following methode in C# code:

```
 DateTime nextDay = new DateTime();
                nextDay = datePicker.SelectedDate.Value.AddDays(1);
```

Now I would like to have XAML handle this, how do I implement this methode to show the selectedDate +1 without writing any C# code?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a  Extension method on string in your project.

Comment: But that would be in C# code, wright?

Comment: yes, you need to have c# code for that

Comment: XAML is a *markup* language and you can't do this in pure XAML. It's not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML will not directly handle this. Obviously you need to write some code in C#. Question is either you want it in Codebehind or as a Converter..

In case you don't wish to write any codebehind, bind your textbox to the datepicker selected value and assign a converter which converts it.